# finding the largest variable

Tags: java, methods, integer

I have below five Integer variables and during the program, they are assigned some values randomly. I want to get the largest variable name but not the variable value. And I want to know if at least two of them have the same value. Please provide an example. Thank you.

```
int politics_counter = 0;
        int economics_counter = 0;
        int foreign_counter = 0;
        int sport_counter = 0;
        int weather_counter = 0;
```

Comment: If you want the *name* then there's big chance you need to save them in Map.

Comment: please give some code snippets. I am a beginner.

Comment: this is kind of a silly question.  The names of variables are irrelevant until they are deemed not to be specifically which then requires hoops to be jumped through, like creating a map, in which case, why would you have them expressed thusly in the first place, etc. etc.

Comment: @ssrp - You will probably get a better answer if you elaborate on *why* you need the variable name. It seems an odd request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And now for an answer (kind of)

```
public class MyThingie {

TreeMap<Integer, String> data = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

public void doIt() {
    ...

    insertElement("politics_counter", politics_counter);
    insertElement("economics_counter", economics_counter);
    insertElement("foreign_counter", foreign_counter);
    insertElement("sport_counter", sport_counter);
    insertElement("weather_counter", weather_counter);

    System.out.println("Highest variable is "+data.lastEntry().getValue());
}

public void insertElement(String name, Integer i) {
    if (data.get(i) == null) {
        System.out.println("Element "+name+" has the name value as "+data.get(i));
    }
    else {
        data.put(name,i);
    }
}
}
```

and now for a more interesting answer:

```
public class BiggestFinder {
    public void showBiggester(Object o) throws Exception {
        TreeMap<Integer, String> data = new TreeMap<Integer, String)();
        for (Field f  : o.getDeclaredFields()) {
            Object v = f.getValue(o);
            if (v instanceof Integer) {
                if (data.get(v)!=null) {
                    System.out.println("Value for "+f.getName()+" is the same as "+data.get(v));
                }
                else {
                    data.put((Integer)f.getValue(o), f.getName());
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Largest is "+data.lastEntry().getValue());
    }
}
```

which will interrogate an object and show the largest field, given that the object has members that are all Integers and that are all accessible to this method.  There's a way to fudge that and improve it to make it more "robust".

Comment: As the OP says, the value can be duplicated.

Comment: but he wants to know if it is duplicated, not what the duplicated value is, he doesn't ask for the name I suppose, so just put found a duplicate instead of the specifics?

Comment: I think the if condition in the first solution is the wrong way round

Comment: @PlexQ: I think instead of `o.getDeclaredFields()` you need `o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()`

Answer (score 1):

As @Max suggested you can use a map for storing your variables and then manipulate the map for finding either biggest variable name or value.

```
// Initialize your map
HashMap<String, Integer> vars = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

// Inserting a variable
vars.put("politics_counter", new Integer(0));

// Looking for biggest variable
String biggestVar = "";
for (String key : vars.keySet()) {
    if (key.length() > biggestVar.length)
        biggestVar = key;
}
```

Comment: You could argue that a HashMap does this in O(2n) rather than O(2nlogn) like a TreeMap, but I think I'd take a TreeMap for ease of use and given how small n is, it just seems nicer.  People should like Trees more anyway.

Comment: You don't need to use a constructor copy of the key, given its immutable.

Comment: also I'm pretty sure the boxing is unnecessary unless you're using a very old version of Java, vars.put("politics_count", 0); should work just fine, or its inferred analog.

Comment: @giorashc Why "=new String(key)" and not just "=key" ?

Comment: Yep, the copying is redundant. Thx for your comment but I hope the point was clear. I used boxing cause I have now idea what JDK he uses.